# PlayOnLinux/Windows Steam store still blank with no-cef-sandbox on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine, steam, playonlinux

I know this question was asked already, but the answer did not help me. I installled play on linux and windows steam, in ubuntu 16.04 and after applying the windows xp settings, wine staging, and no-cef-sandbox, i can download games from my libreary, but not access any thing else in steam, perticularly anything under the store community and username tabs.

Comment: What answer are you referring to?

Comment: the answer that said use the no-cef-sandbox argument and launch in XP compatability mode of PlayOnLinux to solve the all but library tabs being blank

Comment: I got it working, hope my instructions help!

Comment: Should i use a 64 or 32 bit drive

Comment: Steam uses 32 bit (x86).  It is in my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT 11-Apr-2020:** This answer is no longer valid for Steam for Windows running in Linux.  You can try the command `wine steam.exe -no-browser +open steam://open/minigameslist` but I haven't had big success with Steam + Wine much lately.

---

Let me try to do this the best I can for the library to work in Steam.

First get the newest versions of wine installed:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

After that is installed and configured, then run your PlayOnLinux and configure your Steam:

[image]

Configure General settings.  I had to add 3.9 to mine. *You can try different versions to see what works for you)*:

[image]

To add the 3.9 click the `+` on the right of the Wine version box and choose `3.9` on the left side then click the `>` to add it to the right:

[image]

Click on Configure wine to set it to Windows XP:

[image]

[image]

Click on the Install Components tab and install the following listed below the image:

[image]

```
d3dx9_42
vcrun2008
xact
vcrun2015  (if not available choose vcrun2013)
```

---

You can also install using `winetricks` like so:

```
WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam sh /usr/bin/winetricks d3dx9_42 vcrun2008 vcrun2015 xact
```

*Please keep in mind on the above command that vcrun2015 may not exist and you can substitute vcrun2013 in its place.  Also change the .PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam to match your installation.*

---

When complete, launch your Steam:

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer +1. I just don't want PlayonLinux :(

Comment: @OrganicMarble You could always install the components using winetricks.  The reason for this is so that the components are installed with the corresponding app.

Comment: I wanted to try winetricks origionally, but you can't set diffrent librearies from apps like virtual drives, as far as i know, if theres a way i'd like to try it, thanks

Comment: @BaileyJohnston Updated my answer to show using `WINEPREFIX` and `winetricks`.

Comment: For what it's worth, your answer didn't work for me in 2020, this did the trick : `wine steam.exe -no-browser +open steam://open/minigameslist`, from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185938/playonlinux-steam-black-screen-update

Comment: I don't think `-no-browser` switch will allow you to access store and community within steam client as originally asked for...

Comment: @Daddy32 Unfortunately, it keeps changing. So no, it no longer works again.  It changes faster than we can write answers here.

Comment: `-no-browser +open steam://open/minigameslist` is not a fix or even necessary, you could always just go to the View menu and select the mini list regardless of launch parameters (which I've been doing for the last year or so).  I still need access to the store to add new games to my account that are platform-locked to windows

Comment: @EkriirkE You can probably add games via web store interface, using web browser. One thing I have discovered is that it does not seem possible to uninstall a game :(